# Best Javascript Geo chart/map library

Tags: javascript, ipad, charts, geo

What is the best JavaScript Geo map/chart available (high quality solution) ?

It should work on the ipad/android tablets/ie8++/firefox... and ideally with a professional support.

Google Visualization could be a low end solution (no zoom/move, low detail on map...)  but their licensing and lack of support is a problem; note you can not even fix bugs or copy their library.

Protovis is quit impressive but it's not any longer supported and lacks IE compatibilty (again zoom/move).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net) jQuery plugin. You can create interactive vector-based maps with it, wrold, USA and Germany maps are available at the moment. Probably this is what you need.

Comment: nice one, does this library has a support (e.g. we would like to have mode details, add Singapore, Hong Kong...) ?

Comment: Unfortunately there no such functionality at the moment

Comment: In the case we manage a paying client for this functionality would you be ready to extend your library?

Comment: Yes, I'm ready to do this. You can reach me by email (echo.bjornd@gmail.com).

Comment: nice, we will contact you if we decide going for your library

Comment: @bjornd very nice work, do you think it's also possible to add a coordinate system to it? It could open up a lot up use cases for 'small' google maps like behaviour (add markers, etc.), except you wouldn't need to load the expensive google maps api.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. I'm working now on converting maps from shapefiles to svg to have the highest precision of projection. Then it will be possible to add markers by coordinates in (lat,lng) format.